# Rename Tag: [tag: pulsarlostcolony] to [tag: pulsar-lost-colony]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-rename-request

I just came across a question tagged [pulsarlostcolony](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pulsarlostcolony) and per the convention it should be [pulsar-lost-colony](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pulsar-lost-colony), but I don't yet have the rep to rename a tag or retag a question.  It only has the one question.

Comment: Since plural-lost-colony is too close to the existing tag plurallostcolony, this will have to be completed by a mod.

Comment: @Unionhawk Plural-lost-colony?

Comment: @Frank Shh..... >_> (this is why we use hyphens to separate words, so people don't misread tags)

Comment: I can't seem to change it myself as it seems that [tag:plural-lost-colony] and [tag:pluralostcolony] are treated as the same tag?

Comment: @oamlyya True. Therefore a mod must do it, we (as in regular users) cannot only add or remove hyphens from a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a mod has already changed it from [pulsarlostcolony](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pulsarlostcolony) to [pulsar-lost-colony](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pulsar-lost-colony).

[image]